# php continue X - equivalent in c#

Tags: php, loops, c#-4.0, continue

in php :

continue accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many levels of enclosing loops it should skip to the end of.

like

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $countArray - 2; $i++) {
     for ($j = $i+1; $j <= $countArray - 1; $j++) {         
    for ($k = $j+1; $k <= $countArray; $k++) {
            if(condition){
             # found 
             continue 3;
            }
        }
   }
 }
```

What is equivalent  in c# ?

a simple way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really really wanted to do it you could use goto statements:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Level1:

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {

            Level2:

                for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
                {
                    if (k < 5)
                    {
                        goto Level1;
                    }

                    if ( k == 7)
                    {
                        goto Level2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

A goto can be used to get out of deeply nested loops. A C# equivalent for your PHP code could be:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= countArray - 2; i++) {
  for (int j = i+1; j <= countArray - 1; j++) {         
    for (int k = j+1; k <= countArray; k++) {
      if(condition){
        // found
        goto Found;
      }
    }
  }
}

Found:
  Console.WriteLine("Found!");
```